# Convert CP437 using JavaScript Encoding API in Browser

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

Is there a way to convert CP437 to UTF8 in browser using new [Encoding API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encoding_API)?

I've tried this:

```
decoder = new TextDecoder('CP437');
decoder = new TextDecoder('IBM437');
```

but got error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Failed to construct 'TextDecoder': The encoding
>   label provided ('IBM437') is invalid.
>       at :1:11

I've also tried with dashes `CP-437` and `IBM-437`.

On GNU/Linux I can use iconv, I've found project [iconv-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-js), but it seems it only convert one encoding.

Is compiling iconv to JavaScript using Emscripten the only option?

Comment: It seems that there is [node-iconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv) package on npm.

Comment: it seems this encoding label is NOT supported, use either an `iso-xxx` and/or `windows-xxx` encoding (eg look here the polyfill https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding)

Comment: It seems that node-iconv is only for node because it have C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding API is limited and don't support CP437. So the process of conversion look like this:

create empty npm project using

```
npm init
```

then install

```
npm install -g browserify
npm install iconv-lite buffer-shims
```

create index.js file with:

```
window.iconv = require('iconv-lite');
window.Buffer = require('buffer-shims');
```

run

```
browserify -o iconv.js index.js
```

and now you have browser version of iconv lite library (in `iconv.js` file) that will work from browser.

With it you can run:

```
 document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(event) {
         var utf8_str = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(event.target.result), 'CP437');
     };
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
 });
```

you will need to have:

```
<input id="file" type="file" />
```

and

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

so iconv-lite can convert string to utf-8, which is the only valid charset.

If you want already Built JS file, you can access my static assets github repo using jsdelivr:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jcubic/static@master/js/iconv.js

Comment: Thanks, been trying it for hours.   `reader.readAsArrayBuffer`  did it