# Get PC437 encoding for character

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

Im trying to get the PC437 hex for a character in Javascript.

```
console.log('£'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)) // 'a3'
```

if i run toString(16) i get the UTF-16 code for the character which is 'a3' which is correct as per here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

However i need to get 'c9' for that particular character which would be the PC437 hex interpretation for the character?

Comment: I do not understand the question. You have the character `c9` in such table (and the second line has the codepoint ("charCode") lf such character

Comment: I need a method that would have an input of '£' and would return 'c9'. I cant find a way to get 'c9' within javascript for the character '£'.

Sorry if i'm not explaining this well.

Comment: Ah. I think you mean `9c`, the code of `&` in cp437. So your question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315114/convert-cp437-using-javascript-encoding-api-in-browser  (but I do not like the answer. I think it is much easier if you copy the table into your javascript code.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i really don't like the answer there. I really don't want to have to manually override some of these extended characters for cp437 and looking to try and find a way to getting the conversion right without it.

Comment: @Peter I Check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I published a simple package for legacy CP437(CCSID 437) table. [cp437](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cp437)

Usage:

```
const cp437 = require('cp437')

// find by symbol
console.log('// find by symbol')
console.log(`('£', 'hex') -> ${cp437.bySymbol('£', 'hex')}`)
console.log(`('£', 'dec') -> ${cp437.bySymbol('£', 'dec')}`)
console.log(`('â', 'hex') -> ${cp437.bySymbol('â', 'hex')}`)
console.log(' ')

// find by hex
console.log('// find by hex')
console.log(`('B0', 'symbol') -> ${cp437.byHex('B0', 'symbol')}`)
console.log(`('EC', 'symbol') -> ${cp437.byHex('EC', 'symbol')}`)
console.log(' ')

// find by dec
console.log('// find by dec')
console.log(`('175', 'symbol') -> ${cp437.byDec('175', 'symbol')}`)
console.log(`('155', 'hex') -> ${cp437.byDec('155', 'hex')}`)
```

Output:

```
// find by symbol
('£', 'hex') -> 9C
('£', 'dec') -> 156
('â', 'hex') -> 83

// find by hex
('B0', 'symbol') -> ░
('EC', 'symbol') -> ∞

// find by dec
('175', 'symbol') -> »
('155', 'hex') -> 9B
```

Comment: Thanks @abdullokh-mukhammadjonov. I didn't come across this lib when i was looking. The table i have specifies 'c9' for the pound sign character so will test with sending 9C. Im not sure if this is a custom set they have based on PC437 or not. I'll get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Oh wow i didn't realise you put this together to resolve the question. Good job! You 100% deserve the bounty for this. I'll try later to check my c9/9c issue but worst case i can always fork your repo and build a custom table if thats whats needed. Thanks for this!